# lozad in jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

I want to make the images retrieved from my backend in my data table to load faster. I implemented the lozad.js library via CDN and initiated it using Jquery. However, as soon as I implemented it, the images appear to be missing. Can anyone help me with this, I tried searching for solutions but was still out of luck. Thank you in advance.

Image After lozad
[image: After]

my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lozad"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Datatable Starts here
            var table = $('#menu-table').DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "ajax-cstaff-get-menu-item.php",
                },
                'columns': [{
                        data: 'row'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'mitem_pic',
                        render: function(data) {
                            if (data != "") {
                                return '<img data-src="../img/menu/' + data + "?" + new Date().getTime() + '"class="lozad img-fluid rounded" width="125px" height="120px"/>'
                            } else {
                                return ''
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'mitem_name'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'mitem_price'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'mitem_status'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'mitem_id',
                        render: function(data, type, row) {
                            if (data != '') {
                                return '<div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-block"> <a class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm btn-edit" data-id="' + data + '"> Edit </a> <a href= "cstaff-mng-menu-update-pic.php?mitem_id=' + data + '" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm btn-update-pic">Update Picture</a> <a class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm btn-delete" data-id="' + data + '"> Delete </a></div>'
                            } else {
                                return ''
                            }
                        }

                    },
                ]
            });

            // Initialize Lozad library
            lozad('.lozad', {
                load: function(el) {
                    el.src = el.dataset.src;
                    el.onload = function() {
                        // el.classList.add('fade')
                    }
                }
            }).observe()
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: For reference: lozad github: https://github.com/ApoorvSaxena/lozad.js

Comment: hi, any idea why the image is blank ? I tried different init and even changed the cdn, still doesn't work